# When did Debian start requiring i486 and i586?

Tags: x86, debian

According to the [Debian 9](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/i386/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#i386-is-now-almost-i686) announcement, Debian 9 was the first Debian version to require an i686 (P6) CPU for its IA-32 port (named i386). The previous version, Debian 8 required only i586 (P5).

My questions:

- Which Debian version was first to require i586?
- Which Debian version was first to require i486?
- Where are the GCC flags (e.g. `-march=i586`) used to compile C programs from source documented for each Debian version? (It's OK if it's hidden in some .deb package, but where is it?)

Comment: I think i486 were never a requirement: On programming side there is too little for the trouble. Probably it was the same for Pentium. (note: kernel may use optimized version, because both provided some more support for syncronization between tasks, OTOH SMP were not so common). For package, see `dpkg-buildflags`

Comment: `cmpxchg` was new in 586 (https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insCMPXCHG), so I could imagine that being important for libpthread.  Or maybe not since it just provides locks, not lock-free atomics.  486 instructions like `invlpg` are necessary for the kernel to run correctly on 486 and newer hardware.  (386 didn't have a TLB so virtual memory was very slow!)  But that's only the kernel, not user-space.  For user-space, 486 is just `bswap` (endian conversion).

Comment: I'd guess that Debian configured GCC with a default `-march=` (e.g. the default on current systems for `gcc -m32` is `i686` - it will use P6 new instructions like integer `cmovcc` and x87 `fcomi`).  So you might not find `-march=i586` anywhere in a buildflags setting.

Comment: @PeterCordes: The switch to i386 in Debian 9 was explicit, so it has to be configured somewhere.

Comment: I assume you mean to i686.  Like I said, I'd look for i686 in their GCC source package, in the GCC config options of what target options are on by default.  Then other packages built with that GCC will require i686.  (It's also possible that there's a file in /etc with flags for package builds, IDK.)  And separately in the kernel source package, via kernel config settings (IIRC it has x86 architecture options separate from just compiler flags, since it uses its own inline asm for instructions like `lock xadd` and `lock cmpxchg`)

Comment: In older time we had different glibc libraries, one explicitly with 686 instructions. Library would preload such optimization if you had the correct CPU, else if will use default 386 library.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: Sure, but where where is the `gcc -march=i386` flag (or equivalent) specified to instruct GCC to build most of Debian packages in older Debian versions?